# How to get the path of this file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, require

I am new with Nodejs. I want to export from file1.js file to file2.js.
file1.js is located in root-directory and file2.js is in some sub-directory. When I am calling it as `require('/file1')` in file2.js its saying like `Uncaught Error: Module name "/file1" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`. Any help? Sorry if this is silly, but I am new.

Comment: I think `require('file1');` would do it. In any case, can you give us more details about your project structure please?

Comment: No, this is incorrect, this will attempt to load file1 module, from available modules installed via NPM, I believe he is simply missing a . before '/file1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Logger = require('./logger');
```

Requires the module you have written, in a file called logger.js stored in the same directory your code was launched from.(not necessarily the same directory your code is stored in).

```
var someOtherModule = require('../../someOtherModule');
```

Requires someOtherModule.js file two directories back from where the node process is launched.

```
var someOtherModule = require('./subDir/someOtherModule');
```

Requires someOtherModule.js file, sotred in subDir.  subDir is a directory located at the level of where the node process was launched.

```
var awssum = require('awssum');
```

Requires a module installed via NPM, in the node_modules directory from which the process was launched, or any globally installed node modules.  For versioning, the node_modules directory takes precedence.